# Why Scala reports error if does not specify this.type when using chain method in inherited class

Tags: scala, inheritance, chaining

The following code working properly

```
abstract class Base {
  def append(value: Any): this.type = this
}

class Axis extends Base {
  def text(value: String): this.type = append(value)
}

class XAxis extends Axis {
  def position(value: Int): this.type = append(value)
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  new XAxis().text("hello").position(0)
}
```

While if I remove this.type in Axis.text

```
class Axis extends Base {
  // here we don't explicitly specify return type this.type
  def text(value: String) = append(value)
}
```

Scala report

> value `position` is not a member of `Axis`.

The method call chain

> `new XAxis().text` will call `append`
>
> append has the return type `this.type`
>
> `this` is an instance of `XAxis`.
>
> So `this.type` is `Axis`

So no matter whether specify `this.type` as return type, Scala should be always possible to infer to the real instance type.

**Why it works when we explicitly specify the return type `this.type`?**

**But it does not work when we don't explicitly specify the return type `this.type`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't specify the return type of a method, the compiler will infer it. More specifically the compiler will always infer the most precise type, but never a singleton type (which can be recognized by the `value.type` notation). So in this case the method `text` will be inferred to return something of type `Axis`, which is the most precise supertype of `this.type` in the class `Axis`.

Comment: You mean that when call `text`, the compiler knows it as least is Axis, but the compiler will not try to infer the real type?

Comment: Yes. But note that `this.type` is never "equal" to `Axis` or `XAxis`. `this.type` is a singleton type, which means that the only instance of that type is the current object. In your first example `this.type` will be a subtype of `XAxis`, so the compiler knows it has a method called `position`.

Comment: Scala compiler needs some information to infer the type. for method `text`, the only information it has is call `append` which has return type `this.type`. How do we interpreter `never infer to a singleton type`? Since the singleton type is what `text` could get.

Comment: Since it doesn't infer the singleton type, it infers the most precise super type of `this.type` that isn't a singleton type: `Axis`, since the method is defined in class `Axis`.